# Unable to ng-hide elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my [mini-project here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/hjouuqyf/4/), I need to hide the *Shop button* and the *Content div* when the user clicks on the textbox. I am attempting to do it using `ng-hide`.

For some reason there is an error with the module.

```
Error: error:nomod
Module Unavailable
```

I was able to partly get it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7uNSZ/57/), but I need to hide the elements when someone clicks on the textbox, before they start typing.

I need to get this working in Firefox only.

What am I missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/hjouuqyf/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code a bit. You can try this out:

```
<input type="text" name="hideBasicInfo" ng-click="hideBasicInfo = true" />

<div ng-hide="hideBasicInfo">
```

When someone's press the textbox I'll set the property hideBasicInfo true. (via ng-click)

Comment: Thats a great idea! Along with that I also had to wrap the angular library in the head. http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/hjouuqyf/7/